# MC Connect - Salesforce Data Entry Event not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, entry-criteria

I have a few journeys running on Salesforce Data Entry Event that used to work and add contacts and then, while still running, no new contact is added to the journey. 
No change was made to fields or objects I'm listening to with these journeys.

The synchronized DE are still updated with new entries, the connector seems to be working, only Salesforce Data Entry doesn't work anymore.

Changes were made to the API User by SFSC Team, I don't know which ones yet. Could it have an impact on JB Entry Event but not on Synchronized DE ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it *could*, issues like this tend to happen if the tokens are not valid anymore. In situations like these it seems the Marketing Cloud Connector may still work for some functions between the Clouds, but fail without errors for others.

While I don't have a full list of features that tend to break, generally a good indication is also if you no longer see IER's created in Sales Cloud, this is usually the first oddity Users tend to notice.

What I would suggest is to clear the tokens and do some spot checks with MCC functionality (like cross-cloud AMPScript calls, checking for IER's, launching a test SF Data Based Journey etc) before you launch a new version of the real Journey.

- [**Marketing Cloud - Clear Invalid Tokens**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_clear_invalid_tokens.htm&type=5)
- [**Clear User Mappings and OAuth Tokens in MC Connect**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214335&type=1)

On that note you can also double-check if you recieve any error logs on Sales Cloud side for the SF Data Based Journeys.

To do this you'll first need to enable logging in Sales Cloud and try to update/create a record that would normally enter to the Journey on Marketing Cloud. 
If you have an issue with invalid or expired tokens, this will be stated in the log file.

- [**Access Log files on MCC**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000268653&language=en_US&type=1)